# What are the best practices when doing asynchronous calls in a Flux architecture with React?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, redux, flux

I have been working with React/Redux for about two years, but I am currently involved in a React application that uses Facebook's Flux instead of Redux for state management. So I started reading about Flux and the differences from Redux. I stumbled upon something I don't fully understand, and maybe someone here is able to "discuss" the matter a bit!

In Facebook's Flux documentation about the reduceStore's reduce method they state "This method should be pure and have no side-effects" (this sounds a lot like a reducer method in Redux - pure function). But in their own example: Flux async (https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-async), they introduce the DataManager, which handles API calls. This manager is called in their example from within the reduce method. Ergo, the reduce method in their own example is causing a side-effect, making it a non-pure function.

What is the best practice here? And what do you use yourself? Where should these impurities be put?

My "Redux"-inspired approach would be to create a action creator (like in Redux) that is called from the views and this method does the async API call which then dispatches actions. So to clarify my approach would remove the fetching logic (side-effect) away from the store and into some action-creator method instead.

The action creator in sudo code would look something like this:

```
getSomedata(param){
    dispatch({type: GET_SOME_DATA_FETHCING})
    doApiCallAsync()
    .then( () =>{dispatch({type: GET_SOME_DATA_SUCCESS, result: json.result})})
    .catch( () =>{dispatch({type: GET_SOME_DATA_FAILURE})})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Redux, Flux doesn't limit how you handle asynchronous operations at all. The best practice may not exist; it depends on the taste of developers. This is the official asynchronous example in Flux: https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/d95f9b9a06a24ccc8ba6b5742759ea3a383f20c9/examples/flux-async

As you can see, it calls the APIs via `TodoDataManager` right in the store, like [this line](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/d95f9b9a06a24ccc8ba6b5742759ea3a383f20c9/examples/flux-async/src/stores/TodoStore.js#L45) or [this line](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/d95f9b9a06a24ccc8ba6b5742759ea3a383f20c9/examples/flux-async/src/stores/TodoStore.js#L72); it doesn't use action creators. And in the `TodoDataManager`, it also dispatches actions. Personally, I don't really like this approach, or... let's say I don't like Flux.

In fact, I'm migrating a Flux application to Redux. The old Flux application is using a similar approach, and it uses an event emitter to notify components about store changes. The codebase is a mess.

**If** I must use flux, I will use the same approach like yours, which separate the responsibilities clearly and make the codebase easier to reason about. But if migrating to Redux is an option, I will choose Redux anyway.

Comment: I would migrate to Redux if it where possible - but it's not at the moment. 
What I found particular strange in Facebook's own documentation is the fact that they state the reduce function should be pure but in their own example they are not keeping it pure - How are the mortal persons who are not working at Facebook then supposed make a choice, when they can't even follow their own statements. 
Anyway thank you for the answer!